# windows Batch script to check if the subdirectories of a folder are not git repositories

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I excute the bat file from command line

```
@echo off

FOR /D %%a IN (*) DO (

for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('cd %%a ^& dir /a:d ^| find ".git"') do (
if %%g=="" @echo %%ais not a repo
)
)
```

to check if a certain subfolders of a directory are not git repositories, but nothing is displayed in command line when I execute it.

Comment: `if %%g==""` should be `if "%%g"==""` because the match is literal - the strings on **both** sides of the `==` comparison operator must be identical. and `%%g` will never be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what we need to do with this question is work out what the criteria are for a `.git` archive from code that doesn't do that task.

`for /f` will simply not execute the `do` part if there is nothing found (ie. no subdirectories containing `.git`).

So - assuming that a directory with a subdirectory whose name contains `.git` is a `repo` then

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
FOR /d %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO (
 SET "notgit=Y"
 FOR /f %%g IN ('dir /ad "%%b" 2^>nul ^| find /i ".git"') DO SET "notgit="
 IF DEFINED notgit ECHO %%b is not a repo
 IF NOT DEFINED notgit ECHO %%b is a repo
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Find each directory to `%%b` and with `%%b` set a flag assuming it doesn't contain `.git` subdirectories. Find all the `.git`-containing subdirectory names and set `notgit` to *nothing* if any such subdirectory is found.

Then report depending on the state of the flag.

The `2^>nul` suppresses the `No...found` error report and the `if /i` makes the `find` case-insensitive

- and come to think of it,

```
FOR /f %%g IN ('dir /ad "%%b\*.git*" 2^>nul') DO SET "notgit="
```

is probably better.